# Trim null values in AS400

Tags: sql, join, null, ibm-midrange, trim

I am doing a join between two tables A and B on A.Item = B.Item. I am not getting the records as expected. After doing some investigations, I saw that all the items in table B contains nulls at the end of the item.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON TRIMNULL(A.ITEM) = TRIMNULL(B.ITEM);
```

Is there any such method in AS400 to trim the null values?

Comment: Is there a reason that the null-terminators are allowed to remain as part of the data? First thing I'd do is find the source of the weird character and fix it. Second thing I'd do is cleanse the data; it's likely to be problem for a long time to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [TRIM](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscatrimfun.htm) function in the manual.  You can specify a character to trim.

If assuming you mean a hex x'00' when you say NULL.  Then this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A INNER JOIN B 
    ON TRIM(TRAILING x'00' FROM A.ITEM) 
        = TRIM(TRAILING x'00' FROM B.ITEM);
```